Password exposure in shell script
I need to understand if the below code will lead to password leak when the below function is called:
#!/bin/sh

function call_function() {
  password=$1
  echo $password | sed 's/$/\\$/g'
}

password1=$(call_function "abcd")

Will the above function return lead to any security risk?
I did try using ps -ef and trying to catch the password however i was not able to see password getting caught.

You're calling sh with #!/bin/sh but then using bash-specific syntax, e.g. with function. Don't do that. Pick a shell, name it in the shebang, then use the syntax for that shell. In this case, get rid of the word function as even in bash you don't need it, and change your shebang to #!/usr/bin/env bash.

Shellcheck identifies several problems with the code.  The report that it produces includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run Shellcheck on all new and modified shell code.

echo $password doesn't work in general.  echo "$password" is more reliable, but still doesn't work in general.  See Bash Pitfalls #14 (echo $foo).

There are two problems here:

The lack of quoting will break the script, and potentially leak to unintended code execution. See Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells (on our sibling site Unix & Linux) and When to wrap quotes around a shell variable

Anyone with access to a ps listing on this system will be able to see all the commands you are running, including the arguments, including this password argument.
The fact that you did not manage to trivially exploit this yourself does not mean that someone with the right motivation could not figure out how to do it. For example, being able to stop processes or increase the load so that everything runs for a long time will increase the chances that someone could exfiltrate the password. Another approach is to repeatedly run ps and log the results, and then review after a few hours whether any passwords were leaked.
A mitigating factor is that echo and shell functions are shell built-ins, so they will not trivially be leaked to ps; but there are vastly superior risk-free alternatives, so ... just don't play this game.


